# Microsoft Azure Active Directory Exchange Online Custom Application

Tags: azure, office365

I'm attempting to set up a custom application we are creating with Azure.  I've successfully registered the app but I'm not able to add "Office 365 Exchange Online" as an application our app has permission to use.  As a matter of fact its not even one of the apps that show up as an option (see pic). [image]

So I need to know if I'm missing a step. Right now I'm using the free trial of Azure.

Comment: A lot of the Exchange Online APIs can be found under Microsoft Graph API, have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out what it was.  I had to sign up for the developer version of Office 365 and then I could se the Office 365 Exchange Online as an option.